# Can't reproduce the example in lightSlider documentation

Tags: javascript, lightgallery

I'm having difficulty reproducing the functionality demonstrated in the example given by lightSlider's documentation here under the heading "Integrate with lightGallery" (no permalink unfortunately): http://sachinchoolur.github.io/lightslider/examples.html

The functionality demonstrated in the example is exactly what's required in my project. Here is my version of the code that only partially works, these are the problems:

- the right arrow is missing
- zones seem to be unrestricted rightwards, extending beyond the visible image
- after clicking on the image to bring up the lightGallery, it cannot be closed by the X button at the top right

  ```
  <body>
      <ul id="imageGallery">
          <li data-thumb="http://sachinchoolur.github.io/lightslider/img/thumb/cS-7.jpg" data-src="http://sachinchoolur.github.io/lightslider/img/cS-7.jpg">
              <img src="http://sachinchoolur.github.io/lightslider/img/cS-7.jpg" />
          </li>
          <li data-thumb="http://sachinchoolur.github.io/lightslider/img/thumb/cS-7.jpg" data-src="http://sachinchoolur.github.io/lightslider/img/cS-7.jpg">
              <img src="http://sachinchoolur.github.io/lightslider/img/cS-7.jpg" />
          </li>
          <li data-thumb="http://sachinchoolur.github.io/lightslider/img/thumb/cS-7.jpg" data-src="http://sachinchoolur.github.io/lightslider/img/cS-7.jpg">
              <img src="http://sachinchoolur.github.io/lightslider/img/cS-7.jpg" />
          </li>
      </ul>
      <script>
          $(document).ready(function() {
              $('#imageGallery').lightSlider({
                  gallery:true,
                  item:1,
                  loop:true,
                  thumbItem:9,
                  slideMargin:0,
                  enableDrag: false,
                  currentPagerPosition:'left',
                  onSliderLoad: function(el) {
                      el.lightGallery({
                          selector: '#imageGallery .lslide'
                      });
                  }   
              });  
          });
      </script>
  </body>
  ```